# Linux periodic C timers without using signal callback

Tags: c, linux, timer, periodic-task

Requirement is simple - Implement a C periodic timer, which can fire every say x seconds and a timer callback function should be called everytime that timer expires.  Seems a simple enough question and I have browsed the web, but I am finding examples which either have FD and poll involved, or the timer callback is implemented using SIGNAL handler. I want to avoid both. Can you please share some code examples

https://man7.org/linux/man-pages/man2/timer_create.2.html - uses signals, which is not of interest to me as in my processes, there may be other reasons this SIGNAL can be called , how can I differentiate in the SIG-handler, that this signal is for my timer and not other events ?

Comment: "*there may be other reasons this SIGNAL can be called*". Why is that? Why can't you pick a signal that only the timer will generate in the specific process of interest?

Comment: @kaylum: There's a fairly small number of signals available for application use: `SIGUSR1`, `SIGUSR2`, and maybe thirty or so of the `SIGRTnn`.  The application might have a much larger number of timed events that it needs to track.  Fortunately the `sigev_value` field makes it possible to multiplex them, as I mention in my answer.

Comment: that depends on how good this timer has to be (latency etc etc). It is quite hard to archive in Linux as Linux is not a real-time system.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

> how can I differentiate in the SIG-handler, that this signal is for my timer and not other events ?

Check out the [sigevent(7)](https://man7.org/linux/man-pages/man7/sigevent.7.html) man page linked from timer_create(2).  One of the members of the `struct sigevent` that you pass to `timer_create` is `union sigval sigev_value`.  This union isn't defined in the man page, but [POSIX](https://pubs.opengroup.org/onlinepubs/7908799/xsh/signal.h.html) explains that it's simply

```
union sigval {
    int    sival_int;  // integer signal value
    void*  sival_ptr;  // pointer signal value
};
```

Whatever you set here will be passed to your signal handler as the `si_value` member of its `siginfo_t *` second argument, provided you use `SA_SIGINFO` when calling [`sigaction`](https://man7.org/linux/man-pages/man2/sigaction.2.html).  So you just need to use different values here as you set up timers corresponding to different callbacks.  You could use `sival_int` for an integer ID of your own choosing that uniquely identifies this particular timer from all others, or `sival_ptr` for a pointer to a function or some more elaborate data structure that tells you how to handle the timer tick.  Then your signal handler just needs to inspect this argument and dispatch to the callback it specifies.

You might also consider the `SIGEV_THREAD` mode of `timer_create`, which fires off a new thread with the handler instead of raising a signal.  So if you want your callback to run in its own thread, that could be a simpler route to take, as you don't need the signal handler to act as dispatcher.

But if you don't want additional threads, I don't think there is any way to avoid working with signals.  They're about the only mechanism that Unix provides for running code asynchronously.

Do be mindful of the many restrictions on what can be done from within a signal handler; in particular, practically the entire standard C library is off limits.  As such, your "asynchronous" callbacks may not be able to do much except set a flag to tell your main event loop to do the real work at some later time.  So you may not gain much over a synchronous `poll`-type model anyway.

Comment: *within a signal handler ... practically the entire standard C library is off limits* There's no "practically" about it. [Per the C standard, literally the entire standard C library is off-limits](https://port70.net/~nsz/c/c11/n1570.html#note188): "Thus, a signal handler cannot, in general, call standard library functions."  POSIX does provide for the calling of async-signal-safe functions from within signal handlers.  Windows provides similar extensions.

Comment: @AndrewHenle: Yes, I'm speaking in the context of POSIX here (since the question is about POSIX timers), and the "practically" meant "everything except the async-signal-safe functions".  I agree that ISO C's restrictions are even more draconian.

Comment: Hi Nate - Thanks a lot for such a detailed response. I am considering going the thread route now after reading this reply.. However, as my timer is periodic, say every 5s, will I have a new thread being created every 5s and killed by Linux ? Also in the signal method, if I just check for sival_id and call my callback function.. Which process context will my callback function be run, in the process where I initialized the timer and its callback ?

Comment: @Jimmy: The man page doesn't specify whether a brand new thread is created every time, or if there's a thread pool, or what.  As for the signals, the signal will always be delivered to the same process that called `timer_create`, so that's the process in which the handler will execute.

Comment: Thanks again Nate !